Serbian policy on persons who exit Serbia though Kosovo
Just returned back from a trip of Serbia and Kosovo. Landed in Belgrade, got entry stamp. Crossed the border at Merdare, no stamps from either side but passport was taken away for inspection on both sides. Left via Pristina airport, got exit stamp.
What is the Serbian policy on foreigners that have left the country through Kosovo? Do Serbian border guards have a database where they can see that I've entered the country but no record of ever leaving? Do they have a database of people who have crossed into Kosovo?
These questions popped on my flight back home, as I was (over)thinking about the possible repercussions of my itinerary if I ever decide to visit Serbia again with a new passport. Tried googling about this online, but all of the situations I came across were of people who re-entered Serbia with the same passport. In these cases the Serbian border official can clearly see that the person has been outside of Serbia. But didn't manage to find a case with re-entry into Serbia with a new passport without any stamps from foreign countries.

Keep your old passport?

That seems a good reason to ask to keep your old passport when you apply for a new passport, many countries allow for that.
